# Windows Form freezes at progress bar?

Tags: c#, winforms

Ok, so i've built my form application, and it has a loop in it, making a progress bar rise, but the problem here is, when its rising, the window doesn't move or respond, i still can see the progress bar change, i cant close it or anything unless it's finished. This is somewhat annoying because i don't want it to freeze while it test it or have a non-working app until that progress bar has finished. Here is my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar2.Minimum = 1;
        progressBar2.Maximum = nummax;
    }

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= nummax; i++)
    {
        if (i != nummax && !enabled)
        {
            int percent;
            percent = i / nummax;
            string ab = percent.ToString();
            progress.Text = ab;
            Thread.Sleep(50);
            progressBar2.Value = i;
        }
    }
    if (progressBar2.Value == nummax || enabled || progressBar2.Value >= nummax - 30)
    {
        progress.Text = "Completed!";
        progressBar2.Minimum = 1;
        progressBar2.Maximum = 2;
        enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You freeze the UI thread here →`Thread.Sleep(50);`

Comment: @RezaAghaei thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove that `Thread.Sleep(50)`

Add `progressBar2.Refresh()`

or failing that use

```
progressBar2.PerformStep()
```

The system is busy processing, it does not have time to flush windows messages to the controls.

Comment: It works, i dont know why people downvote you since this worked, and is the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why either. Give PeformStep() a try too as this advanced by the amount the Step property is set to.

Comment: I will do that.